# Maven: Reusing code without using parents

Tags: xml, maven, import, nexus

I have several projects that need to inherit from different parents stored in a repository.

```
child-1 -> parent-1 (in repo)
child-2 -> parent-2 (in repo)
...
```

The child pom.xml looks something like this:

```
<project>
    <parent>
        <groupId>com.company</groupId>
        <artifactId>parent-x</artifactId>
        <relativePath/>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>child-x</artifactId>
    <name>Child X</name>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <!-- REPO WHERE PARENT IS LOCATED -->
        </repository>
    </repositories>
</project>
```

Since all the parents are located in the same repo, I'd like to reuse the repositories section in all the child POMs, rather than copy-pasting it. Is there a way to do this?

I can't use the a common parent for these child projects because they each have a different parent, which is not available locally.

Also, adding the repository to settings.xml is not an option because this code will be reused by other developers who might not have their setting.xml set-up properly.

Comment: I'd strongly advice you to urge the other developers to add the repository to their settings.xml. It will help them doing their job - and as you state it, it looks like a viable solution.

Comment: Unfortunately, that is not an option.

Comment: In a company setup the settings.xml of the developers should always look the same which means having setup a repository manager which handles all that. You might add things like credentials for access the repository. If the developers haven't setup their settings.xml it's their problem. Putting repository into a pom is really bad practice. BTW: Where do you deploy your artifacts? Furthermore inheriting from different parents sounds wrong, cause defaults like plugin versions etc. should be defined company wide...

Comment: The parents have a common ancestor where plugin versions are managed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible. There are three mechanisms in Maven to factor out configuration to a place from where it can be reused:

- settings.xml - that you ruled out because some developers might not have set it up
- parent POM - that you ruled out as well due to your setup
- "importing" from another POM - that will not work in your case. Adding a dependency with type "pom" and scope "import" only imports the managed dependencies from the target POM but not the source repository.

I'd personally recommend using the settings.xml and writing a documentation for the developers - or - if you can publish the parent POMs to Maven Central or some internal company repository from where you can use them and which all developers have access to.

Answer (score 0):

Configuring repositories in a POM is a [well known Maven anti-pattern](http://blog.sonatype.com/2009/02/why-putting-repositories-in-your-poms-is-a-bad-idea/#.Va6SuCpVhBc). You should use a repository manager and publish your top level poms there and control access to it via settings.xml.